# Why isn't "that" classified as a relative adverb in "On the day that..."?

Tags: relative-adverbs

I understand "that" in the following can be replaced by "when," which is a relative adverb. But why are there no grammar books that treat the "that" as a relative adverb?

> On the day **that** he returned, we went to the airport to pick him up.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but in my AmE dialect, we'd say ***The day he returned**, we went ...* and  **On the day that he returned** feels like it has a lot of extra baggage. We travel light.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to class these all as subordinators

Comment: Given that ***that*** (or ***when***, or ***on which***, ec.) is entirely *optional* in the cited context, I think there's a strong case for saying it doesn't actually "mean" anything at all. So since it has little or no semantic content, *and* isn't even syntactically required, it's not obvious to me it makes much difference how it's labelled.

Comment: In Hebrew, one word ("asher") stands in for the concepts of who, whom, whose, that, which, etc. Essentially, it is the universal subordinating conjunction, starting any appositional phrase or dependent clause. As with similar words in English, it can sometimes be omitted when the context is clear. English just has more variety of terms for what really are all the same basic idea, and even in English, a person could be referenced by who, whom, that, which, etc., with little to no change in meaning. _"On the day (that) he returned..."_ the word "that" is optional, and not grammatically required.

Answer (score 1):

An adverb in English serves a specific purpose.  It is not the same as an adjective, because it does not modify or explain a noun, nor is it the same as a subordinating conjunction because this is not its purpose.

Adverbs are defined as words that modify adjectives, adverbs, or verbs: and they provide information about *when, where,* or *how.*

When we use the word "when," we change the sense of meaning to one involving a *time* component.

Consider:

- I'm happy *that* you eat healthfully.
- I'm happy *when* you eat healthfully.

In the first example, the word "that" presents the following clause as a mere matter of fact.  No time is specified.  It would be understood from this sentence that "you eat healthfully" always, and that this fact is the reason for my happiness.

In the second example, "when" adds a time component that was not there before.  It would be understood with "when" that I am only happy during those times you eat healthfully, and not at other times.  No assumption is made that you eat healthfully always--in fact, you may rarely do so.  Yes, it also starts a dependent clause, having assumed the position of a subordinating conjunction.  However, it was not the primary purpose of "when" to fill this grammatical role--its purpose was more related to specifying a *time*.

The word "that" does not specify a time, at least, not by itself.  Nor does it specify the manner (how) in which something is done, nor a place (where)--at least, not by itself.

"That" and "where" have two different meanings and purposes within the sentence.  Even where they might seem interchangeable,  they alter the context and are cause the sentence to focus in a different direction.

In the case of the example in the OP,  "On the day" is a prepositional phrase giving a time-related qualification.  Because it acts as an adverb, it can be called an "adverbial."  An adverb, or adverbial, can be modified by another adverb (e.g. "when"), or, when it includes a noun (e.g. "day"), qualified by a parallel (appositive) expression.  These are two separate things, and are not fully interchangeable.

Comment: The point is that in modern grammar "that" is a meaningless subordinator while "when", (and "where" and "while") is a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ, interesting claim. I’d not heard *where* or *while* accused of prepositionality. Can you explain and provide examples? I will say that Merriam-Webster lists a prepositional sense for the latter, though all it says about it is that it’s British for *until*. Perhaps in things like “I’ll stick with you until the end”?  But *while*?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Try *Oxford Modern English Grammar* by Bas Aarts. Most modern grammars no longer regard prepositions as words that often come before a noun (because we don't do that with any other parts of speech amongst other reasons). Most adverbs that look like prepositions and most words previously regarded as subordinating conjunctions are regarded as prepositions by these grammars. Aarts calls prepositions like *while* "conjunctive prepositions".

Comment: Not sure if this meaning-based account is on the right track. After all, one could stretch a bit and say the particular "that" in the OP has grammatical meaning in that it links the following clause to the nominal "day."

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  Aarts is wrong.  English has more refined grammar than some other languages.  In Southeast Asia, for example, the parts of speech are essentially limited to nouns, pronouns, adjectives, verbs, and "extras"--which lumps everything else.  Try teaching grammar with this reduced set of terms!  Adverbs, prepositions, and conjunctions in English are all distinguished by unique functionality within the sentence, and should not be conflated.

Comment: @Biblasia Adverbs are not defined as words that describe verbs or adjectives. That how we describe them for children when they first see them, but adverbs can modify all sorts of words and phrases. And as linguists or serious language enthusiasts, although a word's meaning might sometimes give us a clue as to its word class in the most simple cases, we don't define word classes by their meanings!

Comment: As for Bas Aarts, he is Professor of English Linguistics at UCL, one of the world's most famous universities, where he Is also the Director of the Survey of English Usage, the world-famous research centre, the first in the world to carry out corpus linguistic research, and where world renowned *Comprehensive Grammar of the English language* hailed from. Aarts was the founding editor of the of the *Cambridge journal English language and Linguistics*. He is also famous for his book *English Syntax and Argumentation*, translated into many languages. Why do you think he is wrong?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore I mean no disrespect, but a man's position or fame is of little weight with me.  The world has known many, many people, in many different careers, who have proven unworthy of the credibility others once gave them.  Language is for communication: but when we change the rules, what may seem clear in our own minds may fail to communicate the intended message to other minds who do not share the same perspective.  If Aarts wants to change the rules, he can, of course, make his proclamations.  But, unlike Esperanto, invented to communicate better, will his rules succeed?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore There are literally thousands of English grammar books teaching that an adverb's place is to modify adjectives, verbs, and other adverbs.  Aarts disagrees.  That is his privilege, of course, but he has no ability to enforce his belief on others, the vast majority of whom would likely disagree.  Perhaps he can persuade the textbook writers and dictionary writers of his new classification plan, then gradually introduce it for acceptance in the next generation.

Comment: @Biblasia Noone disputes that adverbs often modify verbs or adjectives. However, few people who have looked at the language for more than ten minutes could argue that that's the definition of an adverb, because there are many adverbs which modify other types of phrase and many adverbs that can't modify verbs, many that can't modify adjectives and many that can modify neither: ***almost** a man* / ***right** in front of the TV* / ***nearly** a million*. Thus grammar books for adults do not define adverbs in this way.

Comment: @Biblasia You just need to apply a few basic first principles, the most important of which are a) don't confuse word categories with meaning and b) don't confuse word and phrasal categories with grammatical relations. Adverbs: cannot pre modify nouns (although they can premodify NPs), cannot appear as complements of the verb *be* (apart from in the ascriptive sense, as in "How I want you to drive os carefully), rarely take their own complements, usually function as modifiers, rarely function as complements.

Comment: @Biblasia **"Perhaps he can persuade the textbook writers and dictionary writers of his new classification"** <--- Erm, there's nothing new in that analysis, though. When I cited *Oxford Modern English Grammar*, I was just explaining where to find what a standard vetted modern grammar reference has to say. The analysis is over 100 years old. See Otto Jespersen, Emonds, Jackendoff, Huddleston & Pullum etc, etc, etc

Comment: @Biblasia In fact, Aarts *is* one of those textbook writers, who has incorporated Jespersen's and others research  into his books!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore Congratulations.  You're the first person to have informed me of this concept, and I've _taught_ English grammar to language learners for decades, from a variety of grammar books, none of which ever deviated from an adverb modifying verbs, adjectives, and adverbs...which, to my view, just shows exactly what I was suggesting earlier--that Aarts' theories have yet to take hold.

Comment: @Biblasia I ought to repeat that these are *not* Aarts's theories. He is just relaying what we already know. I've taught from loads of books that explain that adverbs modify verbs and adjectives **and other phrases**, in particular verb phrases, numbers etc. There's nothing new there. Regarding subordinating conjunctions mostly being prepositions [ edit ] , yes,  you're spot on. EFL books have been notoriously laggardly. They only fairly recently started distinguishing determiners from adjectives! ;-)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore Consider me now better informed as to your perspective, but unconvinced/unaccepting of it based on my own past experience and education.  I hope you will understand.   I can only teach that which formed the foundation of my own education in this area, which did not include these novel definitions.